# Cannot debug phtml-files in Magento2 (xdebug and PhpStorm)

Tags: macos, phpstorm, xdebug, magento2, mamp-pro

For a while I switched over to Magento 2, and now I came across a strange problem:

**Problem:**

The phtml-files are not being debugged: If I set a breakpoint at any line, the debugger does not stop there.

All other files (php-classes, blocks for instance) can be debugged normally. Also the phtml-files of a *Magento-1 Installation* can be debugged normally as well.

**I'm using:**

- Mac OS
- MAMP Pro (for apache and php)
- XDebug
- PhpStorm

**Further Information:**

- I'm running Magento in the developer mode.
- Nevertheless I cleared the cache (using the console) before running a test-request.
- I also cleared the folder var/generation (in other cases that had helped before)

PhpStorm and XDebug should be configured correctly, since usually it works without any problems. So my assumption is, that Magento2 is the problem. Maybe there is a configuration value to set?? Or are the phtml-files merged together before a request?
Anyone had a similar problem?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try placing `xdebug_break();` in such file (programmatic breakpoint) and see if it will work. If not -- collect xdebug log and see what it will have to say (https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) -- such instruction should trigger debug session even if it  is not currently debugged.

Comment: @LazyOne: thanks that worked a little bit. Now the line after xdebug_break(); works like a break point (the debugger stops there). I also took a look at the xdebug-log file, so here is what I found out: the breakpoints that are set in phpStorm are logged with `<- breakpoint_set -i 18 -t line -f ...file.phtml ...->` So obviously the breakpoints-setting works correctly. Nevertheless xDebug doesn't stop there.

Comment: No idea (without seeing actual code/logs). But maybe -- wrong path is used (happens)? breakpoint is set on multi-line statement? other things? Show screenshot of file with not-working breakpoint / working xdebug_break() call.

Comment: @LazyOne what do you mean with "wrong path is used"? Which path do you mean and where is it configured? The only path that is configured for xdebug in the php.ini is the path to the log file, but I guess that is not what you mean.

Comment: same-ish, not using Magento, but I do not get phpunit coverage on my project's `*.phtml` files, which would hint an issue with the file extension, or the opening/closing of php tags in "views" files

Comment: Just a little note to my question, which is kinda old.. Here is a helpful module, which I developed in the meantime to help debugging frontend-template files: https://github.com/espressobytes/debug-hints